# Как обновить правильно несколько записей в БД? Так чтобы не положить сервер

Tags: php

Как правильно обновить несколько записей в БД?

Есть такой массив $update_user в нем такое:

```html
Array
(
    [makaka_kaka] => Array
        (
            [0] => 37.00
        )

    [makdak04] => Array
        (
            [0] => 37.00
        )

    [simba03] => Array
        (
            [0] => 37.00
        )

    [peter02] => Array
        (
            [0] => 37.00
        )

    [tester] => Array
        (
            [0] => 37.00
        )

)
```

И есть такая таблица с именем users

```html
________________________________
| id |    record   |    user    |
|----|-------------|------------|
|  1 |    00.00    | makaka_kaka|
|----|-------------|------------|
|  2 |    00.00    | user4      |
|----|-------------|------------|
|  3 |    00.00    | makdak04   |
|----|-------------|------------|
|  4 |    00.00    | oser0007   |
|----|-------------|------------|
|  5 |    00.00    | peter02    |
|----|-------------|------------|
|  6 |    00.00    | 7788       |
|----|-------------|------------|
|  7 |    00.00    | 8867       |
|----|-------------|------------|
```

Как сделать запрос на обновление, чтобы обновить поле record там где user совпадает с логином из массива.

В поле record нужно вставить то что в массиве у пользователя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($update_user as $user_name) 
{
    foreach ($user_name as $key => $value)
    {
        $upd = 'UPDATE `users` SET `record` = '.$value.' WHERE `user`='.$key;
        mysql_query($upd);
    }
}`
```

Comment: А такой запрос не полижит сервер? В день приблизительно до 40 таких запросов будет.

Comment: Вы когда обрабатываете массив он ложит сервер? - Нет, и в этом случае тоже не положит. Для теста посмотрите нагрузку на БД на хостинге и увидите что ничего не изменилось...

Comment: ну сайт еще в  разработке, просто переживаю чтобы потом на ходу не мучатся. Но как говорится на практике все узнаю Спасибо Вам за помощь.

Comment: Не переживайте, все будет хорошо...